# Is checksumming binary chunks of a large file recommended?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

I am writing a server app which splits large file into smaller chunks and stores them on another external server where other clients can download those chunks and merge them together in one file. For each file there is a meta file where information about those chunks are stored (f.e. how many chunks a.s.o.).

I was wondering if it makes sense to store also the MD5 hash for each file in the meta data, so that the client can easily tell when there are some mismatches or corruption in one file. (and for example download only that specific chunk again).

Since every implementation of such kind was not using any kind of checksumming, I was wondering if this makes sense at all. Also having the performance cost of MD5 in mind.

Comment: Have you read a description of [bittorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent)? It splits files into segments and applies cryptographic checksums to each one. Are you sure that "every implementation of such kind was not using any kind of checksumming"?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I was searching for "splitting large binary files in C#", where I only find implementation without using checksums for each chunk.